# Passing Command Line Args to `open` on Mac

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal.app, command-line-arguments

I am using the `open` command from the Terminal to open an app bundle and would like to pass a command line argument through to the underlying executable.

Is this possible with the open command?

The reason I am using the open command at all here is that it doesn't tie up a Terminal window to support the launched process.  Are there alternate ways to do this other than the `open` command ?

**More Information:**

The application I am looking to run is an open source visualization program (Paraview) which I have compiled myself.  I know that the basic executable does indeed take command line args.  The executable itself is located inside the app bundle `paraview.app/Contents/MacOS/paraview`.

Comment: Can you give more details about which app(s) you're launching? Different apps will deal with command line arguments differently (some will probably just ignore them).

Comment: @Doug Harris - I've added some more info to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per `$man open`, you might be successful with `$open MyApp.app --args argument1`

Of course, you could always just run the executable directly and follow your command with an ampersand—that'll background it.

`$/path/to/My.app/Contents/MacOS/executable argument &`

Comment: Looks like `--args` is a new option in 10.6.

Comment: Following the command with `&` does indeed put it into the background, but the process remains a child of the shell in which it was created.  Avoiding this is one of the advantages of `open`.

Comment: Ah, excellent point--I wasn't aware of that behavior for GUI apps.